# How do I reference the GroovyObject instance from MetaClass methods in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, metaclass

This is a contrived example of what I want to do, but minimally expresses the behavior desired.  I want to reference the instance of the object on which the property access is being invoked.  I tried 'this' first, but that refers to the enclosing class rather than either the MetaClass or the String instance.

```
String.metaClass.propertyMissing = { String name ->
    'I do not exist, but my name is ' + <the String instance> + '.' + $name
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can refer to the object with "delegate":

```
String.metaClass.propertyMissing = { String name ->
    "I do not exist, but my name is $delegate.$name"
}


println "a".me
```